# Cons cells pointing to the same other cons

Tags: list, lisp

I want to create following list in Lisp.

[image: Picture of two cons cells, both cells in the first are pointing to the second, which contains A and B]

```
((lambda(x) (cons x x)) (cons'A 'B))
```

creates this list, but

```
((lambda(x y) (cons x y)) (cons'A 'B) (cons 'A 'B))
```

and

```
(cons (cons 'A 'B) (cons 'A 'B))
```

do not create the list.

My challenge is *why!?* How does the first command create this list and the others do not? Any detail?

Answer (score 4):

Every time `(cons 'A 'B)` is called, a [fresh](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#fresh) cons cell is created, so your second two expressions create *two* "similar" ([`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) but not [`eql`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eql.htm)) objects `(A . B)`,

Comment: I read your nice answer more and more but couldn't get it. would you please add more detail?

Comment: Every call to `cons` creates a new one.  It's hard to see how this could be made any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a `cons` of A and B:

```
(cons 'A 'B)
```

Then you want to refer to it twice from another cons.  So if `x` is a reference to this existing `cons`, you want

```
(cons x x)
```

Wrapping up, we get

```
(let ((x (cons 'A 'B)) (cons x x))
```

or equivalently

```
((lambda (x) (cons x x)) (cons 'A 'B))
```

If you do `(cons 'A 'B)` twice you create two cells:

> <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
>
> <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

and the `cons` of those will contain one link to the first, and another to the second.

(Using a `lambda` to refer to them is a pointless obfuscation; the *point* of the example with the `lambda` form is that you use `x` twice.  The form

```
((lambda (x y) (cons x y)) (cons 'A 'B) (cons 'A 'B))
```

is just a very tedious way to write

```
(cons (cons 'A 'B) (cons 'A 'B))
```

whereas in the original example there is -- pointedly -- only one instance of `(cons 'A 'B)` which you want to be able to refer to twice.)

The purpose of this exercise is to illustrate the difference between "surface" equivalence and identity.  Two lists which contain the same values are still two different lists, whereas two references to the same list are identical.  As @sde hints, this makes a difference for understanding comparisons; the prototypical example is that `equal` is true for distinct lists containing the same values (as well as identical lists, of course), whereas `eql` is only true if its arguments are in fact identical (i.e. they refer to the same object).